# HTML to PHP in expression engine

Tags: php, hyperlink, expressionengine

I am trying to write a PHP oneliner to show a link to another page. This is in Expression Engine. I came with this:

```
echo  '<li><p><a href="{path='Site2/matcha-tea'}">Matcha Tea</a></p></li>';
```

But it gives this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/...../system/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(680) : eval()'d code on line 42

Comment: I do not understand your "Please..." comment at all....

Comment: @Neal please tell me you wrote that not to make sense on purpose :-)

Comment: @ManseUK haha, I fixed it... :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mixing your quotes ... you could do it this way :

```
echo '<li><p><a href="{path=\'Site2/matcha-tea\'}">Matcha Tea</a></p></li>';
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I spent few hours on this. Great help.  Thank you very much again.

Comment: @user1427195 hours ?!?! really ?? you should perhaps read a tutorial or perhaps even try reading the error message ......

Comment: Yes, I should have checked the PHP manual.  Great help. If this system has a point system I want to give 100 out of 100

Answer (score 0):

You have an issuewhere you did not escape the quotes within your quotes.

Try this:

```
echo  '<li><p><a href="{path=\'Site2/matcha-tea\'}">Matcha Tea</a></p></li>';
```

Or you can just escape out of php in general since you are not using any PHP variable in that list item:

```
?>
    <li><p><a href="{path='Site2/matcha-tea'}">Matcha Tea</a></p></li>
<?php
```